# Is it possible to dual-boot Android with LineageOS?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom, lineageos, dual-boot, cyanogen-os

I am going to get a new Android device (Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 with 4G/LTE with latest Android) and I am thinking about the possibility of dual-booting with LineageOS (CyanogenMod fork)? Is it possible? *I own a microSD card if that is a necessity.*

Comment: Sure, but Android doesn't provide built-in support for dual boot. You got to make sure that somebody out in the wild created a hack for your device which can boot Lineage OS or other custom ROMs as well. E.g. MultiROM is the most popular hack out there to do multi-OS boot. It supports many high-end devices such as the likes of Google, Samsung, OnePlus and so on. It would be best if you tell us exactly which device you are  going to buy.

Comment: @Firelord, Thank you for your comment. It will be Samsung Galaxy Tab S3 with 4G/LTE.

Comment: Most if not all tablets don't get popular enough for devs to do a MultiROM port. Also, MultiROM has requirements for the kernel of ROMs you want to boot, which the stock kernel likely won't satisfy (without modification).